# cannot call methods on [widget name] prior to initialization

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, widget

I have initialized my plugin but I keep getting `cannot call methods on collapsableTabs prior to initialization` when I try to call a method in the plugin.

The plugin is loaded and appears fine. I have an input control on the page:

```
<input type="button" id="allOptions" value="Options:" onclick="javascript:populateOptions();" />
```

...

```
function populateOptions() 
{ 
  var optionSelector = $(this).collapsableTabs('allOptions'); <-- FAILS 
}
```

When I click on the button, I get the `error` message.

How do I get around this?

Comment: this will happen only, when you call that widget method before the widget is created. make sure you are not doing that..

Comment: The widget is _created and fully displayed on the screen when this code is called. I can post or email the entire code if you want, but I am certain that (1) the widget has been created and (2) that this error is happening after the creation has completed.

Comment: yes, post the code here.

Comment: I have been drilling into this whole issue for a month now and I am slowly learning. One of the major issues was that I just learned about the difference between a plugin and a widget, but I am still a bit fuzzy around the edges of the details. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

You must first initialize the widget before calling methods on it, ie:

```
$(this).collapsableTabs().collapsableTabs("allOptions")
```

One alternative to this clunky syntax would be to call allOptions() from within the _create() or _init() methods of the widget itself.